# c# parsing HTML

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing, text-parsing

I am trying read plain html from an Excel file (In one column) in C# with NPOI library.

\n\n is missing which is making it difficult to compare HTML for difference. It always shows HTML has changed even after uploading same contents.

(I cannot change HTML as I receive it from different source)

[image: See image b]
Cheers

Comment: this sounds like it is reading escape characters like new-line. can you provide a sample of the output?

Comment: You should include a brief sample of input, parsing code, and output.

Comment: Do you see that slash in debugger window only?

Comment: Are you wanting to parse HTML, or just check if two HTML snippets are effectively the same?